tsconfig.json glob patterns e.g "**/*.{ts,js}" do not work. Is this a bug or expected behaviour?
Why doesn't this work? This glob pattern works for build tools like ESLint, but with TypeScript it fails to resolve the files.
// ❌ Doesn't detect files 
// tsconfig.a.json

"include": [
   "./src/**/*.{cts,mts}"
]

I am doing something wrong here?
tsconfig.a.json should essentially translate to tsconfig.b.json with the glob pattern "./src/**/*.{cts,mts}". That's not the case with TypeScript.
A simple work around for this is shown in tsconfig.b.json.
// ✅ Detects files 
// tsconfig.b.json

"include": [
   "./src/**/*.cts",
   "./src/**/*.mts"
]


Read https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#include - "extended glob" functionality isn't supported.
